# Linear Algebra - Sets equal to R3

Tags: linear-algebra

I was just wondering that when is something equal to R3?

For example, if I have a set X and I say it is equal to R3, it means every vector in R3 must be in X right, so X is an infinite set?

But, if I want to say that every vector in X can be used to reach R3 i.e. this set covers all of R3, then it means that Lin(X) = R3 right i.e. X spans R3?

In the context of sets:
If I have a set of vectors X = {v1, v2, ..., vn}, where all the vectors v1, ..., vn belong to R3.

In this case, do I simply have to show X spans R3? i.e. Lin(X) = R3? Since, all the vectors belong to R3, all linear combinations of the vectors also belong to R3. So I just have to show R3 is a subset of Lin(X) i.e. any vector in R3 can be written as a linear combination of the vectors in X, which can be shown by full row rank right?

I am finding it difficult to say what I need to: but I want to show something is equal to R3, in the case of sets: It can only be shown if that set spans R3 right?

Also, it doesn't require those vectors to be linearly independent right? So, if Lin(X) = R3, X can have n vectors, as long as they have a rank of 3 i.e. it must have 3 linearly independent vectors?

Only for a basis of R3, I must have 3 linearly independent vectors, in which case: the set has full rank (full column and full row rank), and the number of vectors in the basis = no of rows of the column vector in R3 right (showing the number of vectors in the basis = dimension of R3)?

Comment: When you write "R3", do you mean $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: I assume that R3 is $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Let's have a set of vecotrs $X = \{ v_1, ..., v_n\}$ with $v_i \in \mathbb{R}^3$. If you want to show that the set $X$ is a spanning set of $\mathbb{R}^3$ you have to show that $X$ contains 3 linearly independent vectors (in your case). Then $Lin(x) \cong \mathbb{R}^3$. The Wikipedia article about the linear span has nice examples. Last but not least be carefull with the word equal. In this case $X$ is a set and $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a vector space.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. Sorry, I don't know how to write here using formatting, can someone provide the link?

So, for X to span R3, I just need 3 linearly independent vectors i.e. the rank of X when all the vectors in it are written as a matrix must be equal to 3 right? I can have 10 vectors, where 3 are linearly independent and the other 7 are not?

Comment: Yes. And for your other question, take a look here [link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thank you so much both of you :)